# iOS Tab Bar Controller memory management

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller

I am using an iPhone storyboard, which main entry point is a **Tab Bar Controller**. This Tab Bar Controller segues to seven other different View Controllers. These View Controllers are mostly Table View Controllers or even Web Views.

I am not sure if I am searching for a problem, that actually does not exist, but my App uses **~80 MB Ram** after all View Controllers have been opened once and therefore I have the impression, that this is wrong. The size does not exceed after calling the View Controllers multiple times, such that I don't think that I have memory leaks.

I have also searched for this issue, but the only thing, that I could find, was, that the OS caches all of the opened View Controllers and keeps them in the memory. Can someone confirm this? Will the Views be killed, if the OS doesn't have enough memory?

I have the impression, that I, as a good app citizen, should somehow release the memory of each and every View Controller after its `viewDidDisappear`? Or should I just leave the memory management to the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebViews usually crate caches that consumes at least 15MB. 80MB on simulator in my opinion is fine, if you open the same VC and after the first load the baseline is still the same, it's OK.
 You should only care that during memory pressure the system can easily get rid of the unnecessary memory.
TabbarVC keeps the VC instances because is supposed to do so.